# Product space of separable Normed spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, product-space

I want to show that if two normed spaces $X$ and $Y$ are separable then there product space $Z=X \times Y$ is also separable.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** $\overline{A \times B}=\overline{A} \times \overline{B}$. A proof of this can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/302219).

**Hint 2:** Countable product of finite sets is countable.

Comment: That proof is for topological spaces and I am trying to prove it for normed spaces or Banach spaces

Comment: Normed space is a metric space which a topological space.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ is separable there exists $A\subseteq X$ such that $A$ is dense in $X$ and countable.

Since $Y$ is separable there exists $B\subseteq Y$ such that $B$ is dense in $Y$ and countable.

Hint: Prove that $A\times B$ is dense in $X\times Y$ and countable.